# Can we have 1 more type of badge?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I think we can have 1 more type of badge. Something like this:

- 5 answers that are accepted continuously. (Bronze)
- 10 answers that are continuously accepted. (Silver)
- 15 answers that are continuously accepted. (Gold)
- Name = Accepted user

For example, I have done that streak:
[image]

Comment: IMHO, whether a user accepts an answer at all is very random. Wouldn't this badge mostly encourage that answerers pressure op to accept their answer?

Comment: Yeah, pressuring people upvote your own post in the comments is creepy.

Comment: I think they should make a badge for getting an answer accepted and not accepted in a repeating order for 5 times.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We used to have a thing called [acceptance rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate). It was discontinued because answerers used it to badger askers to accept their questions.

I predict this will encourage the same unwanted behaviour.

> Please accept this answer, I need it to get my gold badge...

Comment: Obligatory note that the accept rate is still available through the API

Comment: Obligatory note that leaving comments complaining about a user's accept rate and/or encouraging users to accept answers will be summarily deleted and result in a stern warning from a mod.

Answer (score 14):

No, thank you.

We want to encourage good behaviour, not bad. Getting answers accepted is not something that a user has influence over. Asking them to work towards this badge would mean noisy begging comments such as

> Please don't forget to accept this answer if it helps

We don't want such comments.

Another unwanted effect would be that it might prevent users from answering questions that already have accepted answers or even deleting their unaccepted answers.

On the other hand, there is no good behaviour that this badge would invite. There is no advantage of having such a badge other than inflating the ego of people who receive it.

Comment: Agree with you. I myself have found myself asking for accept. The site gets messed up when all will do

Answer (score 5):

One more note - we want good answers rather answers that OP *likes very much*.

I do think that proposed badge promotes undesired behavior of writing answers that would make OP happy rather that providing good guidance. I.e. "just remove quotes" in SQL injection or code generating JSON/XML with string concatenation will make OP happy in general while in reality is very bad advice. Another example would be answers consisting of just chunks of code without any explanation that happen to solve extremely narrow issue shown in the question rather than showing general solution with an explanation.